# Does a side-effect inside a loop affect its generator?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7, generator, side-effects

In Python v2.7, I have come across a `for` statement over a `for` generator where in the body of the loop the item which is the source of the `for` generator is side effected:

```
for ssid in (ssid for ssid in overlaps if ssid != subseq_id):
  overlaps = subseq_id_to_overlap_ssids_dict[ssid]
```

My question is whether the side effect to overlaps is supposed to affect the `for` generator?  I hope not, but if so, what exactly does that mean?  If I've processed the first matching element and now replaced `overlaps`, would the `for` index into the next location of the new value for `overlaps`?

Comment: Ouch. Regardless of whether it works, I think it's ugly and hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebinding `overlaps` inside the loop won't have any effect on the loop (though mutating it obviously would). Rebinding subseq_iq in side the loop could affect the generator.

A `for` loop evaluates the expression to get an iterator once at the beginning of the loop: in this case the expression is simply the name `overlaps`. Once it has evaluated that expression it creates an iterator from the iterable and uses that iterator to work through the elements. The iterator depends on the object returned by the expression, it doesn't depend on the name used to identify that object (if indeed there is any name).

If this particular case the code is exactly equivalent to:

```
for ssid in overlaps:
  if ssid != subseq_id:
     overlaps = subseq_id_to_overlap_ssids_dict[ssid]
```

This is a clearer way to write it, but again rebinding `overlaps` doesn't change the sequence being used by `for`.

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop operates by iterating its argument i.e. calling `iter` on its argument to produce an iterator, then calling `next` on the iterator until `StopIteration` is raised.

Your generator comprehension argument evaluates the name-expression `overlaps` before the `for` loop is entered, so rebinding the name `overlaps` will have no effect; mutating the object that `overlaps` refers to will have some effect, depending on how iterators over `type(overlaps)` operate.  For example, iterators on `list` increment an index into the list.